# How can I see all files as the administrator in Google drive?

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace

I administrate a Google Apps domain. I'd like to see a comprehensive list of all files under management.  How do I go about doing this?  Is it impossible?

Comment: just noticed that this is a dupe:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727206/how-to-get-all-files-of-all-users-using-google-drive-api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [General Audit Tool](http://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace/viewListing?productListingId=2463+12235622046953943862&hp=staffpick) is a tool in the marketplace, that will show all files and statistics in great detail.

It has a limited free element after the initial 28 day trial for statistics.

Comment: Doesn't seem to exist anymore :/

Answer (score 2):

The short is answer is no. But you can use Google Drive API and build an app on top of it that will help you see those files. If you are building on top of Google App Engine then you can use it as an app for your Google Apps Domain.

Comment: I figured.  If you can draw from an official source, I'm happy to award the bounty.